# RuntimeError in UsersController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have been trying to fix this issue with Heroku for a while now. Whenever I try signing into my application via Devise my it will just throw up an error asking the application owner to check the logs. With that showing, I checked the logs & nothing was wrong. But I couldn't get to the authenticated part of my website.

So I tried changing ApplicationController to DeviseController

that just gives me an unknown action. Please tell me how I can just add show to the Devise controller.

Thank you for taking the time to help me, all answers will help me!

The controller code:

```
class UsersController < DeviseController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_posts = @user.posts
  end

end
```

The error:

Unknown action
Could not find devise mapping for path "/users/1". This may happen for two reasons: 1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example: devise_scope :user do get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end 2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router. If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use: @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]

Also, perhaps someone can guide me threw doing this devise_scope thing. I am pretty to devise authentication & I don't quite understand. I am also fairly new to Rails.

If what I am thinking will fix my Heroku issue isn't anywhere near. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.